# Ionic v1 project fails to build and run on ios/xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Running on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 and using Xcode 10.1

I've got a project that I built on windows for android and have now committed to an SVN and checked it out on a Mac so I can create a platform for ios but I am experiencing a range of errors when trying to build the app, both on a terminal and xcode.

When I run `ionic cordova platform add ios` it seems to be fine and creates a new platform but here is what's shown on the terminal

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^6.1.0
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: ../../../../../users/user/desktop/app/demo/platforms/ios
    Package: io.cordova.app
    Name: App
iOS project created with cordova-ios@6.1.1
Installing "cordova-plugin-android-permissions" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-androidx" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-opener2" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on ios.
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebasex" for ios
Running command: pod install --verbose

[!] The `App [Debug]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

[!] The `App [Release]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-toast" for ios
cordova-plugin-firebasex: Preparing Firebase on iOS
> ionic cordova resources ios --force
> cordova-res ios
[cordova-res] WARN: Source icon "resources/icon.png" contains alpha channel, generated icons for iOS will not.
[cordova-res] 
[cordova-res]   Apple recommends avoiding transparency. See the App Icon Human Interface Guidelines[1] for details. Any transparency in your icon will be filled in with white.
[cordova-res] 
[cordova-res]   [1]: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/
[cordova-res] 
[cordova-res] Generated 47 resources for iOS
[cordova-res] Wrote to config.xml
```

When I go to open the platform on xcode `app/demo/platform/ios/App.xcodeproj` I get

```
The project at '/Users/user/Desktop/app/demo/platforms/ios/App.xcodeproj' cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format. Adjust the project format using a compatible version of Xcode to allow it to be opened by this version of Xcode.
```

Or if I was to open `app/demo/platform/ios/App.xcworkspace` on xcode I get 2 issues:

```
-> Workspace Integrity
->->Couldn't load project
->->->App.xcodeproj
->->Couldn't load project
->->->Pods.xcodeproj
```

If I was to run `ionic cordova build ios` on the terminal, I initially get

```
> ionic-v1 build
[13:08:41] Cannot load gulp tasks: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/user/Desktop/app/demo/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/Users/user/Desktop/app/demo/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/app/demo/gulpfile.js:10:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at loadGulp (/Users/user/Desktop/app/demo/node_modules/@ionic/v1-toolkit/dist/lib/gulp.js:53:24)[13:08:41] Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js
> cordova build ios
```

Which then ultimately fails

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-aafwdjvchhwujxeudzdqnsbyrpgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.o /Users/user/Desktop/app/demo/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build ios exited with exit code 65.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. I've removed the platform and added it again but to no avail. I've also completely uninstall npm and all the packages and reinstalled it and still the same issue. Here's the packages I have installed now after doing an uninstallation.

```
/usr/local/lib
├── cordova@10.0.0
├── cordova-res@0.15.2
├── gulp@4.0.2
├── ionic@5.4.16
├── npm@6.14.10
└── sharp@0.27.0
```

I initially had @ionic/cli in there but removed it as I wasn't sure if it was somehow clashing with ionic. Seems to run fin on android with no issues with adding the android platform and building it via terminal. Any ideas on what other fixes I could try?

Comment: If its purely ionic 1 app. try ionic CLI version 3.20.0.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Do you mean I downgrade my CLI version to 3.20.0?

Comment: Yeah. Back in the days when i was working on ionic 1, CLI 3.20.0 was the most prefect CLI for IONIC 1.